# SQL- finding percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help figuring out the query for this SQL question-

Find the percentage of claims that are processed per state(status) within their SLA per month, for the last 12 months.

Thank you!

```
Id   **l** ClaimID **l** StatusID **l**      CreatedDate        **l** CreatedBy
===========================================================================
1174 **l**   977   **l**    1     **l** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **l**     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1175 **l**   978   **l**     1    **l** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **l**     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1176 **l**   979   **l**    1     **l** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **l**     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1177 **l**   980   **l**     1    **l** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.403 **l**     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1178 **l**   981   **l**     1    **l** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.403 **l**     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is each statusId value a separate state? What is SLA in your example data?

Comment: Yes, each statusid is a separate state. SLA means service level agreement.

Comment: Ok but what has SLA to do with the question? If it's not relevant then it is very confusing adding it to the requirement-

Comment: Also tag the question with the RDBMS you're using

Comment: Ah I apologize, please ignore the "within their SLA" portion.


Using SSMS

Comment: Which DBMS product and what is your expected result?

Comment: I am using SSMS and I do not know what my expected result is. I am new to all of this, I apologize.

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
   SELECT 
    StatusID
   ,count(StatusID) AS CountOfGroupedStatusIDs
   ,sum(count(*)) OVER() AS TotalAmountOfItems
   ,100.00 * count(StatusID) / sum(count(*)) OVER() AS Perc

  FROM Table

  WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())), 0) AND GETDATE()

  GROUP BY StatusID
```

It groups by statusID/States which then counts how many states per group and does a count all in the table to then create a percentage from those values.

The WHERE clause just says FROM TODAY minus 12 months but the beginning date filter is set so that the month is starting from day 1 rather than 12 months from today for example which would be day 27.

If you wanted to change this to 12 months back from today. It would be:

```
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: COUNT OVER is processed *after* aggregation, should be `SUM(count(*)) OVER() AS TotalAmountOfItems`. And there's no need to Cast, this should work, too: `100.00 * count(StatusID) / SUM(count(*)) OVER()`

Comment: Yes you are correct @dnoeth completely missed the sum() around my count(*). Also thanks for the tip about the decimals, did not know that would work.

Comment: As count returns an integer there must be some kind of cast, but multiplying first with `100.00` already changes the datatype to a decimal, float, whatever (depending on the DBMS)

Comment: Ah, I see, usually I just did the casts, I didn't think of giving it a decimal/float type first to turn the rest into that data type also. I will be using this method from now on, thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped me. One more question to add onto your answer- How can I truncate the percentage result column so that the results only show two decimal places? (ex. 86.75 instead of 86.7523434534)

Comment: @snoosan I am sure you can just do a simple ROUND(PercentageColumn, 2). 2 is the amount of decimal places you want. Also, if this answered your question could you tag this answer as the accepted.

Comment: @arahman Will do and thank you. Where would I place the Round(PercentageColumn,2) in the query?

Comment: @snoosan so in the select part where you have the percentage column like this: `,100.00 * count(StatusID) / sum(count(*)) OVER() AS Perc`. You would change it to: `,ROUND(100.00 * count(StatusID) / sum(count(*)) OVER(),2) AS Perc`

Comment: Also, how would I insert a PIVOT statement into this? I would like to show the result set with a PIVOT for the last 12 months.

Comment: @snoosan Maybe add that as a new question as it is slightly adjusting the query more than what I can type in this small comment section. Someone with better knowledge of PIVOT statements can then help you.